# How to get collapse text to open below admin menu?

Tags: 7, theming

I use the collapse text module on my site, when the collapsed text is longer than the screen the collapsed text header gets hidden under the admin menu when you open the collapsible. How can I make it so that it opens and then focuses the header to be just under the admin menu?

if you go to https://arupconsult.com/content/immunoglobulin-disorders/?tab=tab_item-2 and open one of the collapsibles you will see that the header is at the very top of the screen, and when I am logged in to the site the admin menu sites on top of it.

This is a screenshot of one of the collapsibles just opened while logged off.
Notice how IgM is right at the top of the screen.
[image: Logged off]

This is a screenshot of the same collapsible just opened, but I am logged on.
Notice how IgM is now hidden below the admin menu.
[image: Logged on]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue completely, but this sounds as a CSS issue in your theme. Can you post screenshots of what you are referring to?

Comment: I added some screenshots. Does that help it make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS issue; what you need is to move the named anchors up a bit for administrators.

Here's a sample code:

```
/* If you are using the core Toolbar module. */
body.toolbar a[name],
/* If you are using the contrib Administration Menu module. */
body.admin-menu a[name] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  /* This value will be different for Toolbar/Administration Menu modules. */
  top: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aram! btw, totally random somewhat personal question, are you from Armenia, or are you part of the disapora? and so that my question hopefully doesn't sound creepy, I spent 2 years in Armenia, so i recognize armenian names

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, you are correct - my father is Armenian, as well as my name/surname. Hope you had a good time there and enjoyed the food :)

Comment: I did :) The food is amazing! And the people are some of the most hospitable, nicest people I have ever met!

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)